# How to provide an custom delete button in the swipe-to-delete gesture of UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've implemented that default swipe-to-delete gesture in UITableView, and now I feel that this default button actually doesn't look good in the context. Also, it seems to not be localized. In french it still shows "delete" as text.

How can I provide a custom button here? This is how I implemented that guy:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // do stuff, a lot of stuff...really a lot...
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:` in the UITableViewDelegate protocol.

Comment: so that's for changing the title only. But could I also change the button itself? Or must I provide my own implementation then?

Comment: I don't think you can easily change the button, just the title. If you want a totally different button, I *think* you have to totally re-implement the swipe-to-delete gesture, the button animation, everything.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom cell class and include:

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state{
    [super willTransitionToState:state];
    if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) {
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"]) {
                UIImageView *deleteBtn = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 33)];
                [deleteBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.png"]];
                [[subview.subviews objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:deleteBtn];
                [deleteBtn release];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where @"delete.png" is your delete image

Comment: It is _never_ a good idea to use stuff like this: ```[NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"]```. It might break anytime.